# Principal congruence subgroup index in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory

Why has the principal congruence subgroup,

\begin{equation}
\Gamma(N)~=~\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})~|~a\equiv d\equiv 1 ~\text{and}~ b\equiv c\equiv 0~ \text{mod}~N\Bigg\}
\end{equation}

in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})=\Gamma(1)$ finite index,

\begin{equation}
\big[\Gamma(1):\Gamma(N)\big]=\varphi(N),
\end{equation}

when $\Gamma(N)$ and $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ has infinite order, and why equal the index to the Euler-function?

Comment: It's the kernel of a homomorphism onto the finite group ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z}/N{\mathbb Z})$, so it has finite index. I don't believe your claim about the index.

Comment: So it isn't true:  $\big[\Gamma(1):\Gamma(N)\big]=\varphi(N)$ isn't it?

Comment: The index is $|{\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z}/N{\mathbb Z})| = N^3\prod_{p|N}(1-\frac{1}{p^2})$ with $p$ prime. See http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/332/mfms.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :)

Comment: @DerekHolt Could you perhaps possibly provide a hint as to how that homomorphism might look (onto $SL(2, \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$)? I'm trying to find precisely such a one, and I can't make sense of it.

Comment: @Orm You just map all of the entries in a matrix in ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ to their images modulo $N$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. I should have specified that I also need the homomorphism to be an isomorphism. It seems to me that that map cannot be bijective, as several elements in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) /Gamma(N)$ will map to the same $SL(2,\mathbb{Z} /N \mathbb{Z})$. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @Orm What elements map to the same? As $\Gamma(N)$ is by definition the kernel of the map Derek is mentioning, the induced homomorphism will definitely be bijective.